# Why is Ben Grimm the most affected one from the cosmic storm?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four, fantastic-four-2005

In the [2005 Fantastic Four movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four_(2005_film)), it's shown that the eponymous characters (plus Victor von Doom) go to a space station to study a cosmic storm. After some miscalculations, the storm is upon them, and Ben Grimm is outside the station while the rest is inside, protected by a shield. So, the “obvious” scenario is that since Ben is outside, he receives way more radiation than the rest of the team.

However, what really happens is that the shield breaks, leaving all of them exposed, wearing nothing more than their blue suits. But Ben was already outside, and he was wearing a spacesuit, giving him (a little) more protection than the others.

So, why is Ben the most affected by this catastrophe, when he was in fact the most protected one? Is this an error in the film, or is there any other circumstance that actually made him more vulnerable?

> **SUE:** *How come Ben can't turn it on and off like us?*
>
> **REED:** *That's what we're here to find out.*

Comment: what makes you think he was?

Comment: The fact that he's constantly a rock. For comparison, Reed stretches, but can stay in his base form, Sue is visible most of the time, and Johnny is not always on fire. Also, Reed himself says Ben is the most affected (I don't have the exact quote right now).

Comment: The station itself provides shielding.

Comment: He's not "more affected," he's just differently affected. I would argue Susan was the most affected since she got two completely different powers unlike the other three.

Comment: @JayVogler I always thought it was the same power, just utilized in different ways.  Basically her forcefield projection is used to either bend light around her body, or to create air tight fields of various shapes and sizes she can manipulate.

Comment: One of the plots in the movie is about Reed Richards making a machine that will cure them, especially Ben. He promises Ben that he won't rest until he makes it work. I think it's clearly obvious that Ben has the most permanent effects (otherwise he would harden himself at will).

Comment: I agree with Jay: Ben's effect is permanent, and very visible, but that doesn't make it more "severe" except in the eyes of people who cannot see beyond appearances. There's a lesson in there...

Comment: I still consider the fact that he can't control his rockiness a more severe effect (having control of something is not an appearance).

Comment: I would argue that Ben's change is the least severe (when using severe to indicate the degree of change). The Thing's powers are just an extension of abilities that humans already have. He got stronger and tougher, with the downside of contracting a skin condition. The other three gained entirely new ability sets. That is a much more significant change.

Comment: If you use severe to mean the person whose change is the most detrimental to the person, then sure Ben's change was the most severe. However that doesn't mean he was most affected by the cosmic storm. That's just luck of the draw.

Comment: He did have the most exposure to the storm though, that's pretty much without question.

Comment: @JayVogler - The Human Torch also got 2 completely different powers, flight and the flame thing.

Comment: @Richard: He can fly directly because he generates energy with the flames. Susan's powers don't seem to be connected like that because being invisible certainly doesn't create a force field around her.

Comment: @jayvogler - her invisibility is a result of her having cast a light - refracting forcefield around herself.

Comment: It's possible that the ability to change back and forth is due to prolonged exposure to the radiation. Maybe having control over their powers is a sign of the most severe, advanced mutation.